# ipython in cmd erro

Tags: cmd, ipython

I installed ipython in cmd with pip, but when I type `ipython` in cmd and run it
this error comes:

```
'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: use the path to the executable or add it to your $PATH.  This is a windows problem not python

Answer (score -1):

As [@2e0byo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15452601/2e0byo) stated in the comment, it's a windows problem, not python and you have two options to solve it:

1. Executing it by using the path you saved it in.
2. Adding it to the `PATH` variable so you can easily execute it from the command line.

---

**First solution:**

Go to your `path` using the command line. For example, my Python is saved in `C:\Users\serig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`. I used `cd` to go to the directory I wanted and tried to run python which was successful.

[image]

---

**Second solution:**

1. Search for **environment variables**:

[image]

2. Click `Environment Variables`:

[image]

3. Then you have to add your python directory to the `PATH` variable (remember to add it to **system variables** - when I added it to user variables it didn't work). **Click edit**, then **New** and add your python directory:

[image]

After saving everything you should be able to run python easily without going to the directory it's saved in.

[Adding to the path - source](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: In my answer, I used python as an example because I don't have ipython installed, but it's the same process with adding anything to the `PATH` variable.